# Swift Filtering Issue with Turkish Character

Tags: ios, swift, filter

I'm trying to filter an array to get the result according to the textfield text. I have an issue that if my array contains a word `Kadıköy` it won't show it to me if I type it as 'Kadi' in the textfield but if I type as `Kadı` I get the `Kadıkoy` word. I want to get the word in both i or ı.

So please how can I get resolve this issue?

```
self.placeArray = self.placeArray.filter( { (item: SearchItem) -> Bool in
    return item.name.stringByFoldingWithOptions(.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch, locale: NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "tr")).lowercaseString.rangeOfString(textString.stringByFoldingWithOptions(.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch, locale: NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "tr")).lowercaseString) != nil
})
```

Comment: How is the code you posted related to this question? It escapes me. Please add relevant details.

Comment: @EricD. I'm sorry for the long code I have edited it. I hope this helps where it is my issue.

Comment: [This article](http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/) will definitely help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by changing `lowercaseString` to `uppercaseString` and it works now.